# Java Command Line Compilation Not Updating

Tags: java, command-line

I am using eclipse for writing some code, but using the command prompt to compile it because I'm redirecting a file to the input, so initially I compiled the java file and everything went fine, but I then made some changes and when I recompiled the java file it just showed the previous results (not the new results I should have received after compiling), why is this happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I have tried restarting and deleting the files (both .class and .java) and copying the same code to a new java file with the same name, this did not help, but creating a new file with a new name did work....but creating a new file everytime I want to run/test a program is obviously not a solution...

Value of CLASSPATH variable:C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\stdlib.jar;
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\algs4.jar;

This is also what can be seen on my command line:

C:\Users\Owner\colorTest\Algorithms\src>javac QuickUnionUF.java

C:\Users\Owner\colorTest\Algorithms\src>java QuickUnionUF < tinyUF.txt

4 3

3 8

6 5

9 4

2 1

5 0

7 2

6 1

2 components

C:\Users\Owner\colorTest\Algorithms\src>

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? Select your project, then from top menu use `Project -> clean...`.

Comment: "using the command prompt to compile it because I'm redirecting a file to the input"  -- Is that a reason to *compile* from the command line (javac) or to *run* from the command line (java).  Sounds like the later.  Which are you really doing javac, or java, or both, from the command line?

Comment: @Keith i'm doing both

Comment: @Pshemo I just tried cleaning, didn't work :(

Comment: Probably the the classes from eclipse are going to one place, and the classces from commmand line javac are going somewhere else (mabye a directory deeper, or something like that) and your java (runtime) classpath contains only one of those locations, not the one you think.   Add your java and javac commands to the question content for review.

Comment: @Keith I'm using the following: javac QuickUnionUF.java and java QuickUnionUF < tinyUF.txt it works but gives me the results of my very first compilation/run

Comment: The other relevant information is the (a) full command line you are using for (java) along with arguments; (b) the value of CLASSPATH env variable; (c) where in the directory structure you are running javac and java from.  I suggest putting all of this information into the body of the question.  It is essential information in answering this question.

Comment: Also, be absolutely sure that the change you made actually *should* result in different output.  (Thinking it will, when it actually doesn't happens to the best of us sometimes). :-)  Temporarily make the first line of your program something like System.out.println("NEW NEW NEW NEW NEW");

Comment: I'm sure about...I even deleted the whole code in the file saved it and it still worked lol, give me a sec and I'll also give you the information u asked for

Comment: @Keith Did I answer all your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLASSPATH variable:C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\stdlib.jar; C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\algs4.jar;
```

That is probably the problem.

java will look for QuickUnionUF in those jars, instead of in the current directory "."

Try:

```
SET CLASSPATH=
```

I believe this sets the classpath to blank on windows, causing java to use the current directory as the classpath, which is what you want (becuase that is where the output of javac goes).

Or, if you still want to use those jars, then put the current directory at the **beginning** of the classpath.

```
SET CLASSPATH=".;path\to\stdlib;path\to\algs4.jar"
```

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE!!! It worked!!! What i did was add: C:\Users\Owner\colorTest\Algorithms\src to the beginning of the CLASSPATH variable, I wasn't sure what you meant by SET CLASSPATH but it works now...thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in command prompt:

```
cd eclipse-workspace\Project1\src

javaC YourClassToUpdate.java
javaC MainClass.java

java MainClass
```

and your lines in class "YourClassToUpdate" shoud be included